# ¿Cómo puedo darle prioridad entre dos funciones en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo dos funciones en un mismo botón llamado **#enviar** dentro de mi archivo JS, lo que necesito en si es saber si hay alguna manera para que ejecute primero la función de **create** y después ejecute la función de **reload**, no que se ejecuten al mismo tiempo.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#enviar").click(function(){
     create();
     reload();
   });
});

function create() {

    if ($.trim($("#idorden").val())
    && $.trim($("#idusuario").val())   
   ){

       var idorden = $.trim($("#idorden").val());
       var idusuario = $.trim($("#idusuario").val());

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: host + "/Api/API/dolly/",
            data: {
                param: 1,
                idorden: idorden,
                idusuario: idusuario

            }

        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('se mando');

            read(0);

        })
    }

}

function reload() {

    window.location.replace("dollys.html"); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es únicamente ejecutar reload cuando la llamada asincronica recibió un mensaje del servidor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#enviar").click(function(){
     create();
     //reload();
   });
});

function create() {

    if ($.trim($("#idorden").val())
    && $.trim($("#idusuario").val())   
   ){

       var idorden = $.trim($("#idorden").val());
       var idusuario = $.trim($("#idusuario").val());

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: host + "/Api/API/dolly/",
            data: {
                param: 1,
                idorden: idorden,
                idusuario: idusuario

            }

        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('se mando');

            read(0);
            reload(); //En este punto se llama
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Me funciono tu respuesta, gracias.